# Run a c++ binary file that requires library on a different system

Tags: opencv, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04, binaryfiles

I have written c++ Code that requires Opencv libraries to compile in Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to run the binary generated on a different system, it asks for the library. Does this happens, or there is error in code. If no error how can I run the code than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build it on the new system , if it asks for the library, you are not linking correctly.

Comment: How can I permanently link the required libraries to the object file than ?